# How to redirect a same request into two server with nginx?

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

In Nginx, I want to redirect based on the same URL location.

```
https://staging.example.com/healthcheck --> https://preprod.example.com/healthcheck
https://staging.example.com/healthcheck --> https://prod.example.com/healthcheck
```

It means staging subdomain take a request at /healthcheck URL and redirect to preprod and pro at the same time.

All other requests like https://staging.example.com/* redirect to https://preprod.example.com/*.
Is it possible to achieve this with Nginx?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/597697/484449

Comment: @IVOGELOV it's not working, it only redirects into one server. My goal was to receive one request and redirected it into two servers at a time.

Comment: A browser (and nginX, for that matter) can not receive 2 responses for the same HTTP request - you can not redirect the request to 2 servers at a time.